# A recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I generally solve recurrence relations using master method.If it doesn't work then I try substitution method or recurrence tree method.The latter approaches take more time.Recently I came across some recursive relation which I cannot solve using normal method.I don't want rigorous answer(If possible then it's even better). I just want to know if there is any method which will get bounds for this recursive equations.

1) T(n)=T(n/10)+T(9*n/10)+1

2) T(n)=T(n^1/2)+T(n-n^1/2)+c*n

Comment: The Master Theorem applies to 1), unless there's a typo.

Comment: there was typo..thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), the Master Theorem has a generalization for a sum of `T(α.n)` in the right-hand side. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Extension (in French).

As the non-homogeneous term is `1`, you can try a linear solution, `a.n + b`. Then,

```
a.n + b = a.n/10 + b + a.9n/10 + b + 1
```

which works for any `a`, and `b=-1`.

For 2), I have no clue, the argument `n - √n` makes it pretty hard. A linear form doesn't work.